# How to pull code from other github repository (not fork) to my github repository?

Tags: git, github

I have two github repositoryes and I want to pull code from one to another with saving of commit history. How can I do that? Second is not a fork of the first unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a way to pull from one GitHub repo to another directly but you can totally do it manually.

First, pull from your first repo:

```
git pull
```

Second, add the second repo as a new origin:

```
git remote add origin2 <new_repo_url>
```

Finally, push to the second repo (`origin2`, that is):

```
git push -u origin2 <branch_name>
```